# Event not firing on success

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble getting an event to fire and display the var `$contact`. I have tried various options with `$contact` such as: `'".$contact'"` `'.$contact.'` but it's still not firing at all. There are no errors showing in Firebug and would be grateful if someone could point out my obviously nOOb error so I can move forward with this as it's driving me nuts. Many thanks.

I am using a plugin from here: http://pjdietz.com/jquery-plugins/freeow/

```
var $contact = $('<div id="contact" class="freeow freeow-top-right"></div>').html('Your report was successfully submitted and a representative will respond to you shortly.<br /><br />Thank you.');
               $contact.freeow("Title", $contact, {
                    classes: ["gray", "error"],
                    autoHide: false
               });
```

Comment: Simply select the element with `$contact = $('#contact')` then do your operations on the var.

Comment: Could you make a JSFiddle of the relevant code, replacing the `freeow` function with something?

Comment: ...trouble with **display** $contact. Display in console or on screen?

Comment: code shown never puts the element in the DOM. Also doesn't make sense to pass the element as a message argument

Comment: @charlietfl I don't know the code shown being **complete**. His answer itself should point in the right direction.

Comment: @MartinErnst first there is no `answer` only a `question`. I was merely pointing out issues that need clarifying. If you have a solution, feel free to provide it as an answer, otherwise your comment is not very constructive and is just adding noise to the issue